# Android: Rotating an image and setting X,Y position at the same time dynamically

Tags: java, android, image-rotation

so i'm trying to make an app to display the current position of a LEGO Robot in a Path, i'm receiving the data with another existing project and i just have to move dynamically the position of the image in the screen. I have managed to do it (like in a cartesian plane) with setX and setY, and my 'origin' is in the coordinates 'pixels' x= 70, y= 300 of the screen. However when I try to do the rotation (the rotation has to be made counterclockwise, with the origin previously mentioned) it doesn't show me what I expected, doesn't keep the x y coordinates i want. Here is the code for the animation:

```
final View robot = (View) findViewById(R.id.carImg);
//Scale for the X/Y coordinates
float coordX = hmiModule.getPosition().getX();
float coordXScale = coordX*4 + 50 ;

float coordY = hmiModule.getPosition().getY();
float coordYScale = 300-coordY*4; 

robot.setX(coordXScale);
robot.setY(coordYScale);

//code for the rotation with origin (70,300)
robot.setPivotX(70);
robot.setPivotY(300);

robot.setRotation(-hmiModule.getPosition().getAngle());
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!